# How to use a custom sort method with Mulitple Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using a [Bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) with the [Multiple Sort](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/multiple-sort) extension. I have a column with values that are exponents, e.g. 2 x 10-8, 1 x 10-7, 4 x 10-6 and wrote a custom sort method to sort these values. The method works to sort the column when using the "single" sort by setting `sorter: "pValueSorter"` as:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
        exportDataType: 'all',
        filterControl: true,
        columns: [{
            field: 'pValue',
            title: 'P-value',
            sortable: true,
            sorter: "pValueSorter",
            filterControl: 'input'
        }
        ...
```

and then the method as:

```
function pValueSorter(a, b) {
    sort method here
    ...
}
```

When using the MultiplSort extension, is there a way to use this custom method when this column is included in the sort?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you get your column via

```
function pValueSorter(a, b) {
    a.children[colNum]
    b.children[colNum]
    ...
}
```

if you start by 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/08/sorting-vote-count-recently-added-date-javascript/) from 2016 explains how you can sort on multiple columns inside a sorting function.

Basically, if the first check returns `0`, which is falsey, it will process the next check and so on:

```js
var data = [];
(function () {
    var names = ["Logan", "Bub", "Scott", "That-guy"];
    while (data.length < Math.pow(names.length, 2)) {
        data.push({
            age: Math.ceil(Math.random() * names.length),
            name: names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)]
        });
    }
})();
function multiSortData(a, b) {
    return b.name.localeCompare(a.name) || a.age - b.age;
}
function displayData(data) {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.innerHTML = "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>";
    table.border = "true";
    data.forEach(function (data) {
        var tr = table.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).textContent = data.name;
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).textContent = data.age;
    });
    table.style.cssText = "background-color: #eee;margin: 1em;border: 1 solid;";
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}
//TEST
displayData(data);
displayData(data.sort(multiSortData));
```

Comment: The MultipleSort extension for bootstrap-table is generally working, but for the column with numbers with exponents I need to use my custom sort method and am trying to sort out how to use this method with the MultipleSort modal window.